# matrix transformation of deformed rectangle

Tags: transformation, affine-geometry

I am working on [touch screen calibration](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation), and have come across a problem.

My area of touch screen input is a Trapezoid which looks like a square on one side and a triangle on the other.

[image]

(the angle is not even close to that bad, but it is the shape)

I need to transform this shape into a rectangle.

I can apply matrix multiplications, but I don't know if it is even possible to change its shape to a rectangle using linear transformations.

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/413860/265466, linked in the answer below.

Comment: Close. The questions are not the same, but looking at the linked question informed the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a matrix that will transform the Trapezoid into a square. It is linear but not affine. I believe it would be a [Perspective Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413860/is-perspective-transform-affine-if-it-is-why-its-impossible-to-perspective-a?rq=1).

The matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{x}{x_1} & \frac{x}{y}(1-\frac{x_2}{x_1}) &0 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Where $x_1$ is the length of the bottom of the trapezoid, $x_2$ is the length of the top, and $x$ is the length of the rectangle.